# Any notification necessary while redirecting the user to other website?

Tags: website-design, navigation, notification, ux-designer

Is there a need to notify the user when redirecting from one website to other website (of the same brand (maybe a mother site)) ?
**For a clearer image**
My company has a mother site (lets say site A) and a product sub-site (lets say site B) and it has many such products. While the terms and contact page remains the same for all the products on all sites A, B etc. So if a change has to be made on any particular page, it needs to reflect on the pages of all the products sub sites B, C etc. Hence the solution was to redirect the user to the page on site A.
My question is should we notify the user about being redirected and break the sense of a flow for him, or should we create separate pages (terms and contact us) for all product sites and change all of them if there is a change in the page?

PS: i have seen the redirection notice on many sites, but as this is basically the same company, is it necessary to notify or is this approach not advisable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirection notifications are used to protect sensitive user information, for example in case there is a threat of phishing.

Imagine you are logged in to a website that has a forum where users can post messages. If a link in one of those messages would redirect you to an external website that is impersonating the original website, a user could be tricked into thinking they are still in the same environment. The external website might try to abuse this confusion to ask for credentials.

Redirect notifications are used to alert a user they are leaving the environment and prevent possible abuse.

In your case, the user isn't leaving the environment or is send to an unexpected website so the redirect seems harmless. I would say a notification is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting a user to a site inside of your company domain, it is not necessary to show additional notifications.

A notification may be necessary if you are going to change legal and/or semantic context of viewing site.

Comment: so a notification is put only to avoid legal issues?

Comment: Not only legal issues, semantic issues, when people are going from online email account to online shop, and later want to send questions, etc, etc. In general it is put to don't confuse the leaving site and new site by end-user. If leaving site and new site are _the same_ you don't need to show a notification. Showing a notification should have a _purpose_. In your case, when leaving and new sites are in the same domain, there is no purpose for this notification.